# Magento - Indicate on credit memo whether items were returned to stock

Tags: magento

I need to customize the Credit Memo page to store whether or not an item was returned to stock.

I've identified the Observer in:

```
app\code\core\Mage\CatalogInventory\Model\Observer.php
refundOrderInventory()
```

which gets triggered when the admin submits the credit memo with the 'Return to Stock' checkbox ticked. So I know I can add my own observer to write/save something.

But I cant figure out how to add an extra attribute to the Credit Memo product items.

Could anyone give me some pointers?

UPDATE:
I can also add the extra **Returned to Stock** table cell by editing:

```
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\creditmemo\view\items.phtml
```

and

```
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\creditmemo\view\items\renderer\default.phtml
```

To give me this: 
[image: custom column added to credit memo product attributes]

I've hardcoded the "YES" value you see in there. I need to find some way of making this a writeable/readable credit-memo product attribute.

Comment: Extra field as in database or html input field?

Comment: I need to save it, so database. 
That way I can display it on the credit memo, just as text when it is reopened.

Comment: I guess a better way of putting it is, I need to add a returned_to_stock attribute to the credit memo items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to add the attribute and column to your creditmemo item entity, in an install script. Make sure to have your setup class to be `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` as there is no `addAttribute()` function in `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup`.

```
$installer->addAttribute('creditmemo_item', 'returned_to_stock', array('type' => 'int', 'grid' => true, 'source' => 'adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno'));
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/creditmemo_item'), 'returned_to_stock', 'TINYINT(1) unsigned DEFAULT 0');
```

Then, in your observer (please don't modify the observer you listed there), set the value to be true, like so (I just copied the function you listed, and modified it slightly to demonstrate my point):

```
public function refundOrderInventory($observer)
{
    $creditmemo = $observer->getEvent()->getCreditmemo();
    $items = array();
    foreach ($creditmemo->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $return = false;
        if ($item->hasBackToStock()) {
            if ($item->getBackToStock() && $item->getQty()) {
                $return = true;
            }
        } elseif (Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->isAutoReturnEnabled()) {
            $return = true;
        }
        if ($return) {
            $item->setReturnedToStock(1);
        }
    }
}
```