# Magento - Show Whether Item Has Been Returned to Stock on Credit Memo

Tags: php, magento

When creating a credit memo in Magento, you have an option to refund the purchased product and automatically add it back to stock. However, once the credit memo is created it only shows whether the product has been refunded, but it does not display whether it has been returned to stock. I am trying to modify this behavior and display it.

I have written a custom extension for this. It adds a custom 'returned_to_stock' attribute to the Magento creditmemo_item via the install script like so:

```
<?php

 $installer = $this;
 $installer->startSetup();

 $installer->addAttribute('creditmemo_item', 
                          'returned_to_stock', 
                           array('type' => 'int', 
                                 'grid' => true, 
                                 'source' => 'adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno'
                                 )
                         );
 $installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/creditmemo_item'), 'returned_to_stock', 'TINYINT(1) unsigned DEFAULT 0');

 $installer->endSetup();
```

Then I set up an observer to be triggered on 'sales_order_creditmemo_save_after' event:

```
   <events>
        <sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
            <observers>
                ....
            </observers>
        </sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
    </events>
```

In the observer, I have the following public function, which is a slightly modified version of the default Magento refundOrderInventory function:

```
<?php

public function refundOrderInventory($observer)
{
    $creditmemo = $observer->getEvent()->getCreditmemo();
    $items = array();
    foreach ($creditmemo->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $return = false;
        if ($item->hasBackToStock()) {
            if ($item->getBackToStock() && $item->getQty()) {
                $return = true;
            }
        } elseif (Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->isAutoReturnEnabled()) {
            $return = true;
        }
        if ($return) {
            $item->setReturnedToStock(1); // This doesn't work
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that when the observer is triggered and this function is executed, it should set the value of the custom attribute 'returned_to_stock' in the sales_flat_creditmemo_item Magento table to 1. However, for some reason the value doesn't get saved (as noted in the code above). I have tried a number of variations, such as:

```
        if ($return) {
            // None of these work either
            $item->setReturnedToStock(1)->save();
            $item->setData('returned_to_stock', 1);
            $item['returned_to_stock'] = 1;
            $item->save();
        }
```

but none of these work either.

I know that the observer gets fired correctly as I've made it make an entry in the Magento log. It's just the attribute storing that's broken.

I'm aware that this is almost the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378330/magento-indicate-on-credit-memo-whether-items-were-returned-to-stock) and I've largely based my code on the answer in there, but as explained above, the answer to this previous question is not fully working (as such, please don't tag it as a duplicate; I've tried posting under the original question but my post was deleted).

I've spent a number of hours trying to get this to work and I feel like I'm very close to making it work. I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Thank you very much in advance.

**UPDATE (SOLVED)**

OK, I managed to figure it out in the end. To store the value of the 'returned_to_stock' attribute in the database, modify the last bit of the observer function like so:

```
        if ($return) {
            $item->setData('returned_to_stock', 1);
            $item->save();
        }
```

Hopefully this will help someone else trying to achieve the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been a problem for me in the past.

As I look at your code, the first thing that I see is an incorrect attribute type: `creditmemo_item`. If you look in the `eav_entity_type` table, you will see that this does not exist. `sales/order_creditmemo_item` is not an eav entity. You do not need to create an attribute for it. Rather, the column you created is sufficient.

I am expecting that the Magento cache is your problem. Perform a full clear of all the cache (System > Cache Management > Flush Cache Storage). I have, unfortunately, spent some hours troubleshooting, all to find out that Magento is using the cache to determine table structure (for speed optimization), and thus does not look for updated columns.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, SwiftOtter. Unfortunately this is not cache related - I've flushed the cache as well as manually deleted the contents of /var/cache, but the value of the 'returned_to_stock' attribute still doesn't get saved. Regarding the attribute - creditmemo_item is in eav_entity_type table; I'm not sure if I'm missing something?

Comment: OK, I managed to figure it out! This saves the 'returned_to_stock' attribute perfectly well:
    if ($return) {
         $item->setData('returned_to_stock', 1);
         $item->save();
    }
I'm going to update the original question as well.